# Real-time audio processing FIR vs IIR

Tags: audio, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, real-time

My project consists in filtering an audio signal from the microphone, in order to remove noise, and find the time distance between two peeks with the highest precision possible.

I understood that an FIR filter as a linear phase response since the coefficients are symmetric or anti-symmetric, thus there will be a constant delay; so this will let me know exactly the distance between two peeks. Am I right?

Since I'm using an Android device as DSP, I'm trying to reduce as possible the filter coefficients number. Here's my question: can I use a IIR filter for this project or the original wave form will be delayed with a non linear phase, giving wrong results?

**TL;TR;** Can I use a IIR filter to filter an audio signal in order to calculate the real time distance between two peeks?
[image: al-]

Comment: "a FIR filter has linear phase", if, and *only* if, it's really designed with symmetry. Not all FIRs are!

Comment: *Since I'm using an Android device as DSP, I'm trying to reduce as possible the filter coefficients number* laudable, but don't forget that your Android device probably has a CPU running > 1GHz and a audio-rate filter is a ridiculously low load for that (if implemented at least somewhat sensibly).

Comment: *can I use a IIR filter for this project or the original wave form will be delayed with a non linear phase, giving wrong results?* Yes, IIRs can't be perfectly linear phase. But what would be *wrong* about not having linear phase? Yes, you get dispersive properties, but you'd really need to compare the length of your relatively massive peaks to that.